# Handling response after PDF AcroForms HTTP-POST

Tags: pdf, http-post, adobe-reader, pdf-form

I want to inform the user that his HTML Form submission from a PDF file has been successful (or not). Now when I used the browser-plugin with adobe reader I could get a HTML response displayed withing the browser. In the case of using the standalone reader to submit my form I got the "Cannot process content of type text/html; charset=uft-8" error.

My question is: what type/format should I use for my response, that both the standalone reader and the browser plugin can handle.